# Marshalling a JAXB Object Overwrites Previously Marshalled Files

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

So here's a fun one I have yet to solve... I'll start with the code, then some background.

```
public void encodeElements(String path) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.warning("Marshalling config to " + path);
    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootElement.class);

    Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    RootElement ele = new RootElement();
    ele.setDummyField("abc");

    QName qName = new QName("http://localhost/xml-schemas/mySchema", "rootelement");
    JAXBElement<RootElement> root = new JAXBElement<RootElement>(qName, RootElement.class, ele);

    marshaller.marshal(root, new FileOutputStream(path));
}
```

There is a "Save As" option on the GUI of this app. Every time this function is called, it overwrites the previous file saved using the Save As feature. For example:

- Open app
- Save As - "1.xml" - Everything is fine here
- Save As - "2.xml"

  Calling `JAXBContext.newInstance()` overwrites 1.xml with 2.xml's content and also creates a valid 2.xml. Diffing the two files shows they are, in fact, identical. Repeating this process always overwrites the last saved file. (IE Save As 3.xml will overwrite 2.xml and create an identical 3.xml, so on and so forth).

  Stepping through this in a debugger has shown me that `JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootElement.class);` is the line overwriting the previous file.

  I'm at a loss as to where the information on the previously saved file is being recalled from. I've taken to digging through the source ([here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl.java#JAXBContextImpl)), which hasn't been any help. Any help or insight is appreciated.

  PS - That link is the right source. We are on a Java 1.6 platform using JAXB 2.2.11. Any disdain for the platform can be left unsaid, as I share the sentiments.

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. You might very well solve the problem yourself by simply trying to isolate and expose the bug.

Comment: Also, no links to code please. It is in your best interest to make your question as easy to answer as possible.

Comment: My guess is that your problem has nothing to do with the code you've posted, that the issue lies elsewhere, but without a valid MCVE, I cannot test or verify this.

Comment: I see that the link you've provided is to the Java source -- I've fallen into this trap too -- believing that the bug can't be in my code, that I've tested it backwards and forwards and so the bug must be Java's fault -- and I've found myself later to have been wrong  10,000 times to 1. I'm guessing that your odds are as good as mine. First assume that the bug is *yours*, first isolate the bug (the mcve will help with this), and until you can post a valid test case here that proves that it's Java's fault, keep assuming that it's yours.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will edit my post so that it fits those guidelines. By posting the source to Java, I wasn't insinuating it was Java's fault; I am but one lone developer. I was just posting in case I was completely off base in my understanding of how it all works together.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is here:
`marshaller.marshal(root, new FileOutputStream(path));`

The stream that gets passed in isn't closed once writing has completed. So, we had to close it ourselves:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
marshaller.marshal(root, fos);
fos.close();
```

Thanks to those who took a look. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.